# Trying to create a new object form a data model

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a data model like this.

```
data: object = {
  date: '11/11/18',
  data: [3, 4, 7, 2, 5, 6, 8, 8]
 }
```

The data array is from some inputs from the user. Starting from index 0, I would like them to be career, finances, personalGrowth, health, family, relationships, socialLife, attitude.

What im trying to do is get the lowest score (which would be 2 'health') and add it to an object like so.

```
data: object = {
  lowestScore = 2,
  lowerScoreName = 'Health'
}
```

Im fairly new to javaScript and im stuck on how to work this out. 
Thanks

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just make two related arrays (associative arrays) that look like this:

```
data: object = {
    dataTypes: ['Career', 'Finances', 'Personal Growth', 'Health', 'Family', 'Relationships', 'Social Life', 'Attitude'],
    dataValues: [3, 4, 7, 2, 5, 6, 8, 8],
}
```

Then obtain the lowest score:

```
lowestScore: Math.min(this.dataValues),
lowestScoreIndex: this.dataValues.indexOf(this.lowestScore);
```

And set the name of the lowest score:

```
lowestScoreName: this.dataTypes[lowestScoreIndex]
```

And there you go! Here's the full object:

```
data: object = {
    dataTypes: ['Career', 'Finances', 'Personal Growth', 'Health', 'Family', 'Relationships', 'Social Life', 'Attitude'],
    dataValues: [3, 4, 7, 2, 5, 6, 8, 8],
    lowestScore: Math.min(this.dataValues),
    lowestScoreIndex: this.dataValues.indexOf(this.lowestScore);
    lowestScoreName: this.dataTypes[lowestScoreIndex]
}
```